# How to validate this JSON in Swift4?

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable, decodable

There is an API, which wraps its responses in an associative array with a `status` value and a `data` value, where `data` contains either an error object, or the expected values:

Bad Response:

```
{
   "status":"error",
   "data":{  
      "errormessage":"Duplicate entry '101' for key 'PRIMARY'",
      "errorcode":1062
   }
}
```

Successful response:

```
{
   "status":"success",
   "data":{  
      "user": {
        "id": 1,
      }
   }
}
```

I want to validate these responses:

```
public class func validateResponse(_ data : Data) -> WebServicesError?
{
    struct WTPResponse : Decodable
    {
        let status : String
        let data : Data
    }

    do {
        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(WTPResponse.self, from: data) // FAILS HERE
        if let wtpError = try? JSONDecoder().decode(WTPAPIError.self, from: response.data) {
            return WebServicesError.wtpError(WTPAPIError(code: wtpError.code, message: wtpError.message))
        }
    }
    catch let error {
        return WebServicesError.init(error: error)
    }

    return nil
}
```

It always fails when trying to decode the response object with the error: `Expected to decode Data but found a dictionary instead.` I was thinking that I could decode the `data` object as the Swift type `Data`, but it is really a `[String: Any]` dictionary.

1) How can I validate the `Data` I receive from the API?

2) Is there a way I can extract only the "`data`" portion of the JSON response as the `Data` type, so that I can decode the `User` object without having to give it a `status` and `data` properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the other answers state, you essentially can't do this with `JSONDecoder` because you can't decode a `Data` for your `"data"` key. You'd need to decode it as a `Dictionary<String, Any>` or something. I can think of a way to do that, but it's pretty cumbersome, and even then, you end up with a `Dictionary`, not a `Data`, so you'd have to re-encode it to get a `Data` to pass to a `JSONDecoder` later.

Maybe this means you have to drop down to the lower-level `JSONSerialization` and poke through the dictionaries “by hand”. But if you know at decode-time exactly what kinds of responses you are looking for, then I suggest you work with the Swift `Decodable` system instead of bypassing it.

At the top level, you have a response, which can either be a failure or a success, and carries a different data payload in each case. That sounds like a Swift `enum` with associated values:

```
enum WTPResponse {
    case failure(WTPFailure)
    case success(WTPSuccess)
}
```

We want this to be decodable directly from the JSON, but we'll have to write the `Decodable` conformance by hand. The compiler can't do it automatically for an `enum` with associated values. Before we write the `Decodable` conformance, let's define all the other types we'll need.

The type of response is identified by either the string `"error"` or the string `"success"`, which sounds like another Swift `enum`. We can make this `enum` a `RawRepresentable` of `String`, and then Swift can make it `Decodable` for us:

```
enum WTPStatus: String, Decodable {
    case error
    case success
}
```

For the failure response type, the data payload has two fields. This sounds like a Swift `struct`, and since the fields are `String` and `Int`, Swift can make it `Decodable` for us:

```
struct WTPFailure: Decodable {
    var errormessage: String
    var errorcode: Int
}
```

For the success response type, the data payload is a user, which has an `id: Int` field. This sounds like two Swift `struct`s, which Swift can make `Decodable` for us:

```
struct WTPSuccess: Decodable {
    var user: WTPUser
}

struct WTPUser: Decodable {
    var id: Int
}
```

This covers everything that appears in your example JSONs. Now we can make `WTPResponse` conform to `Decodable` by hand, like this:

```
extension WTPResponse: Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status
        case data
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        switch try container.decode(WTPStatus.self, forKey: .status) {
        case .error: self = .failure(try container.decode(WTPFailure.self, forKey: .data))
        case .success: self = .success(try container.decode(WTPSuccess.self, forKey: .data))
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a test:

```
let failureJsonString = """
    {
       "status":"error",
       "data":{
          "errormessage":"Duplicate entry '101' for key 'PRIMARY'",
          "errorcode":1062
       }
    }
"""

let successJsonString = """
    {
       "status":"success",
       "data":{
          "user": {
            "id": 1,
          }
       }
    }
"""

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    print(try decoder.decode(WTPResponse.self, from: failureJsonString.data(using: .utf8)!))
    print(try decoder.decode(WTPResponse.self, from: successJsonString.data(using: .utf8)!))
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

And here's the output:

```
failure(test.WTPFailure(errormessage: "Duplicate entry \'101\' for key \'PRIMARY\'", errorcode: 1062))
success(test.WTPSuccess(user: test.WTPUser(id: 1)))
```

Comment: It's a good model for the example, but I probably should have explained that this format can return more than just `User` objects in a success case depending on the endpoint. I suppose you could do something like: `struct WTPSuccess<T>: Decodable {
    var successVal: T
}`, but that doesn't really mesh with the architecture I've set up, where validation is part of a wrapper that just gets the `Data` object and gives it to the caller to decode. This library is interesting: https://github.com/0111b/JSONDecoder-Keypath. I can validate the status, then access the Data via key path in the caller.

Answer (score 1):

I used [quicktype's multi-source mode](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=swift&s=music) to generate separate `Codable` models for each response type:

[image: multi mode]

And here's the code. You can try to decode a `Response` first, and, if that fails, you can try to decode a `BadResponse`.

```swift
// let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: jsonData)
// let badResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(BadResponse.self, from: jsonData)

import Foundation

struct Response: Codable {
    let status: String
    let data: ResponseData
}

struct ResponseData: Codable {
    let user: User
}

struct BadResponse: Codable {
    let status: String
    let data: BadResponseData
}

struct BadResponseData: Codable {
    let errormessage: String
    let errorcode: Int
}

struct User: Codable {
    let id: Int
}
```

I think this is a bit neater than trying to express this as a single type. I also suggest not selectively decoding the JSON, and rather decoding all of it, then picking out the data you want from these types.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where Swift4 Codable doesn't work. You have to parse the JSON manually and take care of the cases. 
https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you'd go about doing this with the new `Codable` feature, as shayegh says.

You could instead use the `JSONSerialization` class. That would convert your JSON data to a Dictionary that contains other dictionaries. You could then interrogate the dictionary yourself through code.

That would be pretty easy.

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to avoid unnecessary serialization, due to some responses being quite large.

Comment: If you don't want to deserialize the whole response then neither JSONSerialization nor the Decodable protocol is a good choice. Both of those deserialize the entire object graph at once. There are other third party libraries that let you walk the object graph step-by-step. The ones I remember are in C, so using them from Swift would be a bit of a challenge.